# REDUCER***How to update a specific object in an array?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array containing objects and have edited one of these objects and would like to replace it with the newly updated object in my reducer.
Its failing to update, any ideas?
My inititalState looks like this and I have updated the object in details based on the id...my payload has the newly updated object.

```js
const initialState = newTimesheetDetail:[dayNo:0, details:[{id:2, name:'Bob', age:55}]]
```

```js
        case EDIT_DETAILS + '_FULFILLED':
            const detailToEdit = state.newTimesheetDetail.filter(item => {
                let date1 = new Date(action.payload[0].workDate).withoutTime().toString();
                let date2 = new Date(item.date).withoutTime().toString();
                if (date1 === date2) {
                    item.details.map(e => {
                        return e.id === action.payload[0].id ? {...e, ...action.payload[0]} : e
                    })
                }
                return item
            })
            console.log('detailToEdit', detailToEdit)
            return Object.assign({}, state, { newTimesheetDetail: detailToEdit })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to update"? Are you getting any console errors or unexpected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function doesn't change the original array, it returns a new one. Here, you need to return a new `item` object with the updated details.

```
if (date1 === date2) {
  const newDetails = item.details.map(e => {
    return e.id === action.payload[0].id ? {...e, ...action.payload[0]} : e
  })
  return { ...item, details: newDetails }
}
```

Comment: Sure thing! Don't forget to mark my answer as correct while you're at it c: